# CodeBuild, get the list of folders that have changed files inside them buildspec.yml

Tags: amazon-web-services, git, aws-codebuild, buildspec

Im trying to make my first build on aws and this is my `buildspec.yml`, I was just testing if my command does work on codebuild

```
version: 0.2

env:
  git-credential-helper: yes
phases:
  install:
    runtime-versions:
      nodejs: 16
  pre_build:
    commands:
      - aws codeartifact login ...
  build:
    commands:
      - changed_folders=$(git diff --dirstat=files,0 HEAD~1 | awk '{print $2}' | xargs -I {} dirname {} | awk -F '/' '{print $1}' | sort | uniq)
      - echo $changed_folders
```

this command works on local but when it is building

```
git diff --dirstat=files,0 HEAD~1 | awk '{print $2}' | xargs -I {} dirname {} | awk -F '/' '{print $1}' | sort | uniq
```

theres an error saying

```
fatal: ambiguous argument 'HEAD~1': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
Use '--' to separate paths from revisions, like this:
'git <command> [<revision>...] -- [<file>...]'
```

I tried changing the `HEAD~1` with `$CODEBUILD_WEBHOOK_HEAD_REF` it works but im getting an empty result when I echo using `echo $changed_folders`

Im using github as my repository

Reference: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/userguide/build-env-ref-env-vars.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normally Codebuild Systems (Jenkins, Github Action, Codebuild) fetch only last commit of (triggerred ref only), so that when you run some git commits about git history you will get empty. So that by default build systems clone source code like `git clone --depth 1 -b <branch> <repo_url>`.

AWS [announced](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2020/09/aws-codepipeline-now-supports-git-clone-for-source-actions/) you can fetch full history clone in codebuild.

When you enable artifact option "Full clone" on your pipeline, you will be able to get `changed_files`

Comment: but im not yet using codepipeline, im not sure how to use that lol

Comment: This repo can help you to manually fetch all history of git. https://github.com/TimothyJones/codepipeline-git-metadata-example

Comment: you can set Clone Depth to "Full" in advanced section of codebuild source, and you should be able to have entire revision history